# Lottery algorithm - PHP - math seems good, but is the function valid?

Tags: php, algorithm

I want to make a custom lottery extraction to motivate users to participate in an online experiment. The rules are:

- 10% to get 10$
- 1% chance to get 50$
- 0.1% chance to get 500$

The lottery is a PHP function that gets called once and returns the prize (0, 10, 50 or 500). I created the function below, and after 70 000 trials the statistics are:

- 9.11% for 10$
- .91% for 50$
- .01% for 500$

Should I be worried about the algorithm? Is there a better way to create a good distribution of chances than mt_rand ?

```
function lottery() {
  // winnings before extraction
  $win=0;

  // choose a winning number between 1 and 10
  $target=mt_rand(1,10);

  // make three independent extractions, each with 1/10 probability
  if (mt_rand(1,10) == $target) {
    // if first extraction is the winning number -> prize=10
    // probability: 1/10
    $win=10;

    if (mt_rand(1,10) == $target) {
        // if second extraction is ALSO the winning number -> prize=50
        // probability: 1/10 * 1/10
        $win=50;

        if (mt_rand(1,10) == $target) {
            // if third extraction is ALSO the winning number -> prize=500
            // probability: 1/10 * 1/10 * 1/10
            $win=500;
        }
    }
  }
  // return the prize
  return $win;
}
```

Thank you for helping a newbie!

Comment: If you look at the 10$ prices then the deviation from the mean is of 0.89 which is far more than the standard deviation for it (sqrt(0.1*0.9)/sqrt(70000) ~= 0.0011). So something is (most probably) going wrong here although I am not able to spot it.

Comment: By the way, the target value needn't be random. The test `10 * mt_rand() < mt_rand_max()` should work as well.

Comment: Yet another way is to draw in range `(0,999)` and check for `0--`, `00-` or `000`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: but in that case the probability of winning $ 10 is 9%: 10% minus the chance of winning $ 50 or $500...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have four outcomes with given probabilities:

- 0.1% probability to win $500.
- 1% probability to win $500.
- 10% probability to win $500.

The fourth outcome - no win - is 100% minus the sum of the other three outcomes, namely 88.9%.

Mark Gabriel has explained why your initial code was off: By promoting 10% of the people who have won $10 to $50 winners, you take them away from the pool of $10 winner, which will be only 9% of all people.

Pham Trung has contributed a solution that takes the winners of higher amounts from the pool of non-winners so far and adjusts the probabilities. That's a workable solution, but the easiest solution is in my opintion to call the random number generator just once.

This solution also reflects the ticket analogy best: You place 10,000 tickets in a box. The 1,000 tickets from 1 to 1000 win $10. The 100 tickets from 1001 to 1100 win $50. The ten tickets from 1101 to 1110 win $500. All 8890 tickets from 1111 on don't win anything:

```
function lottery() {
    var pick = Math.floor(10000 * Math.random());
               // random number in the range [0, 10000).

    if (pick < 1000) return 10;
    if (pick < 1100) return 50;
    if (pick < 1110) return 500;

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, the tickets have only their number written on them. You pick one. Then you check whether the ticket number is eligible for $10. If not, you check the *same ticket* whether it may bet a $50 win. There is really just one random action involved.

(I've used a zero-based random-number function in Javascript instead of PHP's `mt_rand`, but I think the solution is clear.)

Comment: Thank you! I have underestimated this problem. Mark Gabriel clearly pointed out the flaw, but you got - in my opinion - the easiest solution. I've changed your code to PHP and got this results for 100000 simulations: (10$ = 10.084; 50$ = 1.015; 500$ = 0.1) (10$ = 9.901; 50$ = 1; 500$ = 0.099). I will go with your solution.

Answer (score 12):

That's because the true chances of getting each in your code are :

$10 - `0.1*0.9` = **9%**

$50 - `0.1*0.1*0.9` = **0.9%**

$500 - `0.1*0.1*0.1` = **0.1%**

---

This is not because of `mt_rand()`. This is just a statistics problem. Try running more iterations, and you'll see the numbers converge to the numbers above.

As you can see with the calculations above, you don't get $10 by getting it right the first time, you get $10 by getting it right the first time (10%), AND getting it wrong the second time (90%).

Following that logic, you can extend the same math for $50 (getting it right the first two times, 10% and 10%, THEN getting it wrong on the third time, 90%), and for $500 (you get the drill).

With your specific code, the computations for the true probability is as above.

---

See code in the accepted answer for the correct code with accurate probabilities.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is math, guys. -- oops, sorry. @YvesDaoust, I was in the process of editing the answer.

Comment: Thanks @YvesDaoust - I ran iterations of the same code using JavaScript - even reaching 1000000 iterations, and I was really puzzled why the numbers don't amount to `10%`. Then I realized it was a math problem from the start. I'll attach the JavaScript code I used so others can try on their browser console.

Comment: Doesn't your corrected code suffer from the same flaw? The 50$ win is achieved with dice rolls from 11 to 100, hence 90/10000 = 0.9%. The limits should be accumulated: 10, 110 and 1110.

Comment: Your solution is not correct, for example, case $dice <= 100, the probability that it happens is 99.9*(90/10^4)% which is not 1%. @MOehm even your suggestion is not correct too, 99.9*(100/10^4) is not 1%

Comment: Oh my, it is indeed my error. Haha. Thanks for pointing that out, @MOehm. I'll edit the correct answer.

Comment: This seemingly simple problem is getting more and more complex. I stand by my math, but my code, I shall fix and test with statistics.

Comment: You could make it independent tests and throw the dice again after each test.

Comment: That's what I was thinking @RyanVincent, but I'll have to test with statistics just to be sure.

Comment: Another way is to use non-overlapping ranges with one dice. It seems to give the required distributions. I am using trials with 1 million 'throws'. with both `mt_rand` and another randon number generator based on the `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`.

Comment: @PhamTrung: Whan I posted my comment, there was only a single dice roll from 1 to 10,000 inclusive whose result was kept in a variable `dice.` With only one roll, my suggestion is correct: 10 out of 10,000 get $500, 100 (namely rolls 11 to 100) get $50 and 1000 get $10. 8,890 people out of ten thousand (not 9,000) people get nothing. (I'm not sure why this simple problem should be solved by several calls to the random number generator. You have 10,000 tickets in a box. You draw one. End of story.)

Comment: @PhamTrung: I don't think your math is poor. The answer you gave is good, just a bit more complicated than it needs to be, in my opinion. When you commented and said my solution (in the comments) was wrong, you were probably also right, because you judged my comment against updated code. The lengthy comment above was just me in self-defence mode.